# cgi with c programming

Tags: c, cgi

I'm trying simple example -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
 {
 printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
 printf("<html><title>Hello</title><body>\n");
 printf("Goodbye Cruel World\n");
 printf("</body></html>");
 return 1;
 }
```

compiled and moved to apache docroot - but when i click on url - it comes as a popup and asks where to download/save this binary file? how to fix this?

Comment: sorry,whats that link it ? I cann't find  cgi stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless you already have other CGI scripts running in the same place, this is harder than just plopping a file somewhere - some stuff has to be configured in the web server to make it possible: apache settings, the `.htaccess` file, permissions, and so on.

Make sure you read the [Apache Tutorial on CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/cgi.html) to be up to date with what needs to be configured.

Answer (score 2):

Check the similar one here but its **c - cgi**

- http://computer.howstuffworks.com/cgi3.htm
- [CGI Scripting in C++](http://nwfolk.com/cppcode.html)

Method is same